# how to type these: ヶ,々?

Tags: discussion

how to type these: ヶ,々? directly on keyboard.

Comment: You can probably get 々 by typing "noma" into your IME.

Comment: This is a regular question, not a meta one.

Answer (score 7):

On Windows 7 it's 'lke' for ヶ and 'onaji' for 々.

All the possible small kana can be typed by prefacing them with "l".

Comment: "x" is also an alternative to "l". xtu = っ

Comment: "x" is more widely supported across OSes than "l" AFAIK.  "くりかえし" also works for "々"

Answer (score 4):

Usually I just type the word that it is in.

For example:

> ひとびと -> 人々
>   さまざま -> 様々
>   さんかげつ -> 三ヶ月

々 repeats the previous kanji, often with rendaku. By itself it can be spelled "noma" because it looks like the katakana ノマ smashed together.

ヶ may look like the katakana ケ, but it is not. I usually see it in the pattern (number)ヶ月, where it is pronounced か, confusingly enough. The most efficient way I know to type it by itself is to first do かげつ -> ヶ月 then hit backspace. Edit: Ciaran's suggestion of typing lowercase L then "ke" works on Google IME, nice.